# Permanently Reformat Variable Values in SAS

Tags: sas, format, put

I am trying to reformat my variables in SAS using the put statement and a user defined format. However, I can't seem to get it to work. I want to make the value "S0001-001" convert to "S0001-002". However, when I use this code:

```
put("S0001-001",$format.)
```

it returns "S0001-001". I double-checked my format and it is mapped correctly. I import it from Excel, convert it to a SAS table, and convert the SAS table to a SAS format.

[image]

Am I misunderstanding what the put statement is supposed to be doing?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Show your format definition.

Comment: I added the format image above, does that help?

Comment: That format should work fine. Please post an example where it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you tried something like this it should work as you intended.

```
proc format ;
 value $format 'S0001-001' = 'S0001-002' ;
run;
data want ;
 old= 'S0001-001';
 new=put(old,$format.);
 put (old new) (=:$quote.);
run;
```

Make sure that you do not have leading spaces or other invisible characters in either the variable value or the START value of your format. Similarly make sure that your hyphens are actual hyphens and not em-dash characters.